# How to interpret extreme small coefficient for all predictors in logistic regression model?

Tags: regression-coefficients

I am trying to build a prediction model of outcome of intervention. I used the logistic regression model, and Calibration and discrimination was confirmed very well. but the final model shows very small coefficient for all predictors.
How can I interpret them? Are they not associated with outcome?
My sample is only 90 samples.

```
Call:  

glm(formula = outcome_m6 ~ lesion_size + index_cat.x + pain_score.x, 
    family = binomial, data = data_prediction_model_lesion_size_NA)

Coefficients:
   (Intercept)    lesion_size2    lesion_size3    index_cat.x2    index_cat.x3  
     1.954e+01      -2.025e+01      -2.167e+01      -3.694e+01      -1.885e+01  
 pain_score.x1   pain_score.x2   pain_score.x3   pain_score.x4   pain_score.x5  
    -1.830e+01       2.115e+01       1.410e+00       1.816e+00       4.113e-01  
 pain_score.x6   pain_score.x7   pain_score.x8   pain_score.x9  pain_score.x10  
     5.722e+01       2.028e+01       2.014e+01      -2.533e-11       2.170e+01
```

Comment: have you scaled these predictors?

Comment: If a coefficient is small or not depends on the range of the individual predictors in your dataset. If the predictors are kategorial variables, I would say that most coefficients are pretty big, in the order of magnitude of the intercept term. This is probably why @JohnMadden asked if you scaled the predictors